# SQL SUM with JOINS

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, count

I'm trying to make a query that shows all movie details and the total number of tickets sold for that movie.
Here's my table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCHrN.jpg

Here's my code so far:

```
SELECT Movies.MovieID, Title, Released, Runtime, Classification, 
SUM(Tickets.SessionID)
FROM Movies 
LEFT JOIN Sessions ON Movies.MovieID = Movies.MovieID 
LEFT JOIN Tickets ON Movies.MovieID = Tickets.SessionID
GROUP BY Movies.MovieID 
ORDER BY Released
```

Here's the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmbhU.jpg

Here's the outline of the database;

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Movies";
CREATE TABLE 'Movies' ('MovieID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 'Title' TEXT,'Released' INTEGER, 'Runtime' INTEGER,'Classification' TEXT, 'Plot' TEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Tickets";
CREATE TABLE 'Tickets' ('TicketID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 'SessionID' INTEGER,'PricePaid' REAL,'TimeStamp' INTEGER);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "MemberTickets";
CREATE TABLE 'MemberTickets' ('TicketID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,'MemberID' INTEGER,'OnlinePurchase' INTEGER);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "MovieGenre";
CREATE TABLE 'MovieGenre' ('MovieID' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'Genre' TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('MovieID', 'Genre'));
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Sessions";
CREATE TABLE 'Sessions' ('SessionID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 'MovieID' INTEGER,'SessionTime' INTEGER, 'NormalPrice' REAL, 'SeatsAvailable' INTEGER, 'RoomID' INTEGER);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Members";
CREATE TABLE 'Members' ('MemberID' INTEGER primary key autoincrement ,FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, Postcode TEXT );
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Please make an [mcve]. I.e. provide a tailored toy database by showing a few lines of "create table..." and "insert...".

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `COUNT()` and your second `JOIN` condition is not correct.

```
SELECT m.MovieID, m.Title, m.Released, m.Runtime, m.Classification, 
       COUNT(t.SessionID)
FROM Movies m LEFT JOIN
     Sessions s
     ON s.MovieID = m.MovieID LEFT JOIN
     Tickets t
     ON t.SessionID = m.SessionID
GROUP BY m.MovieID, m.Title, m.Released, m.Runtime, m.Classification 
ORDER BY m.Released;
```

Note that the `GROUP BY` includes all the unaggregated columns in the SQL.

Notice that I also included table aliases and qualified *all* the column names.  You should always qualify all column names when a query has more than one table reference.  Table aliases make that easier.

Comment: Hi Gordon I should mention that this is SQL lite. When I tried your query I got errors, could you explain why you've replaced all my table names with single characters also?

Comment: @r92l30 . . . The second question is easy:  As explained in the answer, the query is easier to write and to read.